# Program to remove trailing blanks not working! :(

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

Recently I've been working on an excercise from K & R's C book, wich states: write a program to remove trailing blanks/ tabs from each line of input, bla bla bla.
I've tried A LOT of ways using functions and didn't work. So I decided to put everything inside main() and it just doesn't work either! Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_INPUT 100
#define ACTIVE 1 //quit with Ctrl + C

void main(){
    int i, nb, nt;
    char c;
    char line[MAX_INPUT];
    char corrected[MAX_INPUT];  

    while(ACTIVE){
        //get current line
        for(i = 0; i < MAX_INPUT - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
            line[i] = c;
        if(c == '\n'){
            line[i] = c;
        }
        line[i + 1] = '\0';

        //correct current line
        nb = nt = 0;
        for(i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++){
            if(line[i] == ' '){
                nb++;
                if(nb == 1)
                    corrected[i] == line[i];
            }

            else{
                if(line[i] == '\t'){
                    nt++;
                    if(nt == 1)
                        corrected[i] == line[i];
                }

                else
                    corrected[i] == line[i];
            }
        }
        corrected[i] == '\n';
        corrected[i + 1] == '\0';

        //print corrected line
        printf("%s", corrected);    
    }
}
```

So, by the time I want to print the "corrected" version of the current line, it prints this instead:

```
�
```

I'd really appreciate the help. I've been trying this the whole week and it's driving me crazy the fact I can't find the error xD
Thanks for your attention, folks! :)

Comment: You should seriously invest in some static analysis (linting), or better compiler flags. Placing your program in my editor, before I even compile it I get [5 warnings, and 5 notes](http://i.imgur.com/SiYKEsV.png) from `clang`. `gcc bad.c -Wall` shows [similar warnings](http://hastebin.com/xayuyixufa).

Comment: Kernighan and Ritchie would say that it is `int main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
corrected[i] == line[i];
corrected[i] == '\n';
corrected[i + 1] == '\0';
```

to

```
corrected[i] = line[i];
corrected[i] = '\n';
corrected[i + 1] = '\0';
```

`==` is an equality operator, while `=` is an assignment operator.

Comment: Well, now it does something! It's not printing the rest of the line though, just the first word, but that would be another topic. Thank you very much, mate!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the comparaison operator `==` instead of the assignment  operator `=`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, mate! But I don't get it. How is it overflowing? I made the correction, and there's no difference.

Comment: Don't worry! I got it now :) I just don't get the overflow thing.